# How to change only first string of multiple same value on mysql row

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a mysql query that replace a string on a row as below;

```
UPDATE users 
SET user_online = user_online - 1,
    connectedSRV= case when connectedSRV= '1.1.1.1' then 
                                             REPLACE (connectedSRV, '1.1.1.1', '') 
                       else REPLACE(connectedSRV, ';1.1.1.1', '') 
                   end 
WHERE username='$common_name'
```

However, i may use same value multiple times in the row like ;

```
1.1.1.1;1.1.1.1;1.1.1.1
```

Once i tried to execute update sentence , it replaces all '1.1.1.1' values but i want to delete only one. So the result should be;

```
1.1.1.1;1.1.1.1
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Normalise your data structure and store these entries in records, not in a single row.

Comment: Check the [MYSQL String functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Correct way:**

Normalize your schema and ensure that every column contains atomic data (First Normal Form).

CSV column is violation of this simple rule. You should avoid it.

---

**Workaround way**

Use simple string manipulation:

```
UPDATE users 
SET user_online = user_online - 1,
   connectedSRV= 
   CASE WHEN connectedSRV= '1.1.1.1' then ''
     WHEN connectedSRV LIKE '%1.1.1.1;%' THEN
          concat(left(connectedSRV, instr(connectedSRV,'1.1.1.1;')-1),
          substr(connectedSRV, instr(connectedSRV,'1.1.1.1;')+ length('1.1.1.1;')))
     WHEN connectedSRV LIKE '%;1.1.1.1%' THEN
          concat(left(connectedSRV, instr(connectedSRV,';1.1.1.1')-1),
         substr(connectedSRV, instr(connectedSRV,';1.1.1.1')+ length(';1.1.1.1')))
     ELSE connectedSRV
     END
-- WHERE username='$common_name'
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33d4dd5/1/0)**</kbd>

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════╦═══════════╦══════════════╦═════════════════════════════════╗
║                 initial                 ║ username  ║ user_online  ║          connectedSRV           ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1.1.1.1;1.1.1.1;1.1.1.1                 ║ aaa       ║           9  ║ 1.1.1.1;1.1.1.1                 ║
║ 1.1.1.1                                 ║ aab       ║           7  ║                                 ║
║ 1.1.1.1;2.1.1.1                         ║ aac       ║           7  ║ 2.1.1.1                         ║
║ 3.1.1.1;1.1.1.1                         ║ aad       ║           6  ║ 3.1.1.1                         ║
║ 4.1.1.1;1.1.1.1;3.1.1.1;1.1.1.1;1.1.1.1 ║ aae       ║           4  ║ 4.1.1.1;3.1.1.1;1.1.1.1;1.1.1.1 ║
║ 1.2.3.4                                 ║ aaf       ║           3  ║ 1.2.3.4                         ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════╩═══════════╩══════════════╩═════════════════════════════════╝
```